# Get routes via message passing

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

So I run several chatbots via `child.fork(../bots/config1.js)` and so on. I want to make a web interface for said chat bots to display some data. Since they're child processes, they can't access the same port. Right now I'm doing redirects when I start the bot. For example, in my start file, it looks something like this:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var express = require('express');
var web = express();
var basehref = 'http://bot.example.com';

var configs = {
  'bot1':{ port:3001,file:'bot1.js',route:'bot1' },
  'bot2':{ port:3001,file:'bot2.js',route:'bot2' }
}

for (var bot in config) {
   var cfg = config[bot];

   child.fork('bots/'+cfg.file);

   web.get('/'+cfg.route,function(req,res){
     res.redirect(basehref+':'+cfg.port+'/'+cfg.route);
   });
}
```

And I have the bots start their own express server on `cfg.port` to handle that request. But it feels tacky.

This is the route in the bot file:

```
web.get('/'+cfg.route,function(req,res){
  var data = { cfg:cfg,local:local,users:users,modules:{} };
  for (var i=0;i < loadedModules.length;i++){
    var module = loadedModules[i];
    data.modules[module.type] = { 
      settings:module.settings,
      toggles:moduletoggles 
    }
  }
  res.render('views/routeIndex',data);
});
```

So I was wondering if there was any way I could send the data to the child process, and then return the data to the wrapper and make the page there, keeping all the bots on the same port.

I've already tried using cluster, but the routes are complex in the bot file, and therefor can't be defined before the bot is fully operational, and I spent several hours trying before giving up.

Comment: You can send messages between fork processes and parent process. Example and docs: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle

Comment: I know that, I already do so the bot can reboot itself. It sends a message to the wrapper and the wrapper kills the process and reboots it. But how do I send data INSIDE a route, and then get the data from on('message') to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

File bot1.js

```
// this bot echo the message it received
process.on('message', function (message) {
    process.send('Bot says:' + message.toUpperCase());
})
```

File app.js

```
var child = require('child_process'), express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bot1 = child.fork('bot1.js');

app.get('/bot1/:message', function (req, res) {
    bot1.send(req.param('message'));
    bot1.once('message', function (reply) {
        res.end(reply);
    })
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Run:

```
npm install express
node app.js
```

On browsers or curl:

```
http://domain:3000/bot1/hello%20how%20are%20you

Bot says:HELLO HOW ARE YOU
```

Comment: Okay, this actually looks like what I need, I'll try it in a few. However, will the `once` interfere with the message handling I have in place already? Because the bot sends a message when it needs to reboot itself. I'm going to try it anyway, but I like to be reassured :P